# Create name of a list out of a string

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json data, And I want to sort it in java. For every category that is not existing, I want to create a new List. after that or if the category exists, I want to add the data "desc" "title" "link1" and "link2" to it.

```
        if (jsonStr != null) try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray products = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Products");

            // looping through All products
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                String category = c.getString("category");
                String title = c.getString("title");
                String desc = c.getString("desc");
                String link1 = c.getString("link1");
                String link2 = c.getString("link2");


                // tmp hash map for single contact
                // HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                List<String> Product = new ArrayList<>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                Product.add(category);
                Product.add(title);
                Product.add(desc);
                Product.add(link1);
                Product.add(link2);

                if (!categories.contains(category)) {

                    List<List<String>> [category] = new ArrayList<>(); //here I want to create the name of the new list dynamically if it's not existing yet

                }
                [category].add(Product);

                // adding contact to contact list
                categories.add([category]); // and finally adding the category to the categories list ( List<List<List<String>>>)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your new `category` ArrayList to your `categories` and keep a reference on it. You can use the handy method of `get()` from the `Map` to hit two flies with one stone e.g. something like this

```
List<List<String>> yourCategoryList = null;
if((yourCategoryList = categories.get(category)) == null){
    yourCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.put(category, yourCategoryList );
 }    
yourCategoryList.add(product);
```

Comment: thanks. but the name of `yourCategory` is in this case only `yourCategory`. how can I change this if there is `Category1`, in the next array of the json `Category2`?

Comment: @EmanuelGraf You are talking about variables. You can name them however you want. Your categories are inside your Map<String,..>. With `categories.get("Apples")` you are getting the `List` for the apples and so on,.

Comment: @EmanuelGraf I adjusted the code to reflect it better. You add the categories like this `categories.put(category, yourCategory)`

Comment: i have all the time `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @EmanuelGraf You have to initialize a Map (HashMap) first before you can add stuff into it.